# DD-WRT to redirect incoming traffic to a home Plex server

Tags: dd-wrt

I am not sure if this is possible, however I have domain with DNS only (no hosting) pointing to my home DD-wrt border router. I have setup port forwarding from port 80 to port 32400 of a windows computer running Plex media server.

Currently I have to connect via mydomain.com/web/index.html, I can not change this through Plex, so I was wondering if I can setup my DD-wrt router to redirect mydomain.com connections to mydomain.com/web/index.html?

Is there anyway I can achieve this?

Comment: what are you trying to do, access plex from outside your LAN?

Comment: Yes, and I can do so ok, I am just trying to make it a shorter URL.

Comment: Are you using Chrome? Is this for you or another user?

Comment: Chrome and it is for me when I am on break at uni. Why do you ask?

Comment: Answer below if for you.  If it was for a friend or family you can do the same thing with sharing libraries in the plex server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Head to the Chrome App store and install the Plex app.  With this app you can sign into your plex account (you have to create one, its free).  It will access your plex server from anywhere and stream your content to you, no port forwarding needed.  It works for android as well.  This is currently how I use my plex server from anywhere.
EDIT: Depending on internet connection to plex server you may have to change the remote viewing options so it does not stutter/buffer.

Comment: I already have an account so I'll check out the app, cheers for the tip.

All my port forwarding is working fine for the web based player, it is purely for elegance sake that I would like have a shorter URL.

Comment: Did this work for you?